# How to uncompress http response in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-http

I using an API which compresses the response with brotli, the google chrome automatically uncompressing and showing the response. But flutter is showing compressed code which is encoded with br.

Lemme know how to uncompress the response. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can pass the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header and get the response in Gzip format which is automatically uncompressed by the HTTP client.